# Smooth background images transition - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://www.chooseyourtelescope.com/ (>> Please watch it on a minimum 15'' screen, the site is not entirely responsive yet and you wont see what I'm talking about)

When you hover the buttons (moon, planet, etc...) it changes the background. But the transition is buggy on Chrome (image0>blank>image1). And worknig on IE11 but sometimes with a lag. I didn t try with the other browsers.

How to make a smooth transition?
A quick fade Image0>image1, not image0>transition color>image1

Here is the code for the MOON button. Thats the same with the others. 
*(I don't know anything about Javascript. I found the script below on Stackoverflow.)*

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-logos-home" id="top-logos-moon-front"><img src="moon-logo.png" alt="MOON"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-home {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-image: url(Frontpage.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     display:inline;
     top:0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('.image-home');
    $('#top-logos-moon-front').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("Frontpage-moon.jpg")')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using the **opacity** property. Now its working perfectly.

**HTML**

```
<img id="background-moon-front" class="hover-backgrounds" src="Frontpage-moon.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
.hover-backgrounds {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#top-logos-lune-front").hover(function (e) {
    $("#background-moon-front").css("opacity", "1");
    }, function() {
        $("#background-moon-front").css("opacity", "0")
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change just your script code if you want smooth transtion.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('.image-home');
    $('#top-logos-moon-front').hover(function(){
        $body.fadeOut('slow',function(){
          $body.css('background-image', 'url("Frontpage-moon.jpg")').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

---

If you want to do best solution for this you need follow the steps below.

Firstly you need to defined your path of images in the js with the below code.

```
var imgs = [
  'http://i.imgur.com/DwLjYhh.jpg',
  'http://i.imgur.com/gAlqfUU.jpg'
];
```

After this step, you need to add new attiribute your buttons like data-id.

```
<div class="top-logos-home" id="top-logos-moon-front" data-id='0'>
   <img src="button_image_jpg" alt="MOON">
</div>
```

When you defined all variables, you need to detect the hover with your current code and choose the right image that is in imgs array for your background.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('.image-home');
    $('#top-logos-moon-front').hover(function(){
     $body.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        //fade out slowly element and after change the style of inner elements then fade in slowly.
        $body.css('background-image','url('+imgs[$(this).attr('data-id')]+')').fadeIn('slow');
     });
    });
});
```

In my personal opinion; Image transitions shouldn't manage in this way. Create different element for each planets. When user click the button, planets slip and overlapping. You can see a demo in the below code.

http://codepen.io/thegeek/pen/GDwCa

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont understand the first step, can your explain me more?

Comment: Actually, you can skip the first step but if you skip it, you need to defined and set image of url in fuction. You know the urls  and you can fetch them from css or html by using Jquery. When user hover on your button fetch the url from css and concat the new style in js after show them slowly with fadeIn.

Comment: Man dont forget Javascript is like chinese for me :/ Can you show me the code with the urls I gave you : "Frontpage.jpg" and "Frontpage-moon.jpg"?

Comment: I can not help you now beacuse I am in mobile. I will edit the code as soon as possible for your requirements.

Comment: I put the code for the moon button only. And its actually working on Chrome too

Comment: The code is working on my chrome. (44.0.2403.155) If you want to change the duration of transition you can put the miliseconds instead of "fast" or "slow" like fadeIn(20,function(){...})

Comment: The problem is not the duration of the transition, but the transition itself. The fact there is a "blank" between the 2 backgrounds...

Comment: I am sorry to help you in this fact. Maybe you should try to change your html and javascript code.

Comment: You can try css3 transitions without js. Good luck.

Comment: If you shrink your problem and defined on jsfiddle and codepen, i can help you on your problem.